# Is a diaphragm pump good for pumping liquid soap?

Tags: pumps

Can a double motor diaphragm pump be used for continuous pumping of liquid soap? Can it take it?
[image]

Comment: I'd assume it depends on the material used for the diaphragm and its compatibility with the liquid. Different rubbers are very different with regards to chemical compatibility.

Comment: what does the picture have to do with the question?

Comment: Perhaps you should define what you mean by "good". continuous but most efficient? continuous but flow rate adjustable? accuracy of flowrate? cost per unit mass? cost is not relevant?

Comment: @jsotola just to tell what kind of pump I've got at hand. It isn't a AODD, I guess. I was thinking of this pump as its easily available and is cheap.

Comment: @SolarMike I just need it to be continuous, and get a reasonable flow rate, like 4-5 liters per minute at least. And not die in the process by the effort involved. I expect the pump to be on 12 Hours each day every day.